# How to create HTML via Javascript from JSON input?

Tags: javascript, html

This is reality

[image: This is reality]

This is the expectation

[image: This is the expectation]

What I'm trying to do here:

I have JSON data of 60 elements with nested data inside. I am currently able to successfully display them via hard coding. This is easy because I only display 5 results now. But, I need to display all 60. This, obviously, is highly inefficient to hard-code, not to mention bad practice.

But injecting HTML via JS has got me stumped.

```
for (var c = 0; c < 20; c++) {
  html += '<div>';
  html += '<div class="card text-center">';
  html += '<div class="card-header">';
  html += '<h5><strong id="name'+c;'"></strong> - <span id="sv'+c;'"></span>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="card-body text-left">';
  html += '<ul style="list-style-type:none;">';
  html += '<li><strong>Flights:</strong> <span id="flights'+c;'"></span></li>';
  html += '<li><strong>Contributed:</strong> <span id="cont'+c;'"></span></li>';
  html += '<li><strong>Cont/Flight:</strong> <span id="cpf'+c;'"></span></li>';
  html += '<li><strong>Avg Cont/Day:</strong> <span id="avgcd'+c;'"></span></li>';
  html += '<li><strong>Joined:</strong> <span id="join'+c;'"></span></li>';
  html += '</ul>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '</div>';
}  
console.log(html);
//console.log(allCont, allJoined, allFlights);
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
```

This is the code I've written to attempt this, but it outputs something very undesirable as in seen in the "reality" photo. This is the code, in normal HTML, I'm trying to inject:

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5><strong id="name0"></strong> - <span id="sv0"></span></h5>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body text-left">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
      <li><strong>Flights:</strong> <span id="flights0"></span></li>
      <li><strong>Contributed:</strong> <span id="cont0"></span></li>
      <li><strong>Cont/Flight:</strong> <span id="cpf0"></span></li>
      <li><strong>Avg Cont/Day:</strong> <span id="avgcd0"></span></li>
      <li><strong>Joined:</strong> <span id="join0"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The loop ending at 20 is just a sample run. What I need it to do is of course loop through the length of the JSON file, which is of course just a matter of replacing "20" with "data.length".

The IDs need to graduate as well, e.g., name0, name1, name2 for each bootstrap card I'm trying to output here.

What stumps me here, though, is that the `console.log(html)` outputs an HTML structure that looks good to me:

```
<div><div class="card text-center"><div class="card-header"><h5><strong id="name19</div><div class="card-body text-left"><ul style="list-style-type:none;"><li><strong>Flights:</strong> <span id="flights19<li><strong>Contributed:</strong> <span id="cont19<li><strong>Cont/Flight:</strong> <span id="cpf19<li><strong>Avg Cont/Day:</strong> <span id="avgcd19<li><strong>Joined:</strong> <span id="join19</ul></div></div>
```

I hope I have explained the problem, do ask for more details as required. Thanks!

Comment: _"`html = '<div>';`"_  you reset `html` at the start of each loop

Comment: Oh no! So I should start with html+=?

Comment: @Phil That seems to have made it worse manifold - https://ibb.co/QY3pqBC

Comment: You could do that (I'd also add `let html = ''` before the loop) but honestly I'd look into some sort of HTML templating engine. Building strings of HTML with concatenation is prone to many problems. FYI, I think those semi-colons after each `c` aren't helping. They should be `+`

Comment: if you can give us a data test, we can help you better, because your code can be improved with a Document Fragment to accumulate every item, and template literals to avoid errors like add extra characters or something like that.

Comment: @Phil That actually just solved my issue, thanks! I'll look into the template engine solution and see if that makes things more efficient.